# How to scrape a table from a page and create a multi-column dataframe with python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, data-science

**This website https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/ DB begins from year 1902 to 2022.
I am trying to scrape the table, narrative, probable cause and classification for every accidents in the year 2015 and 2016: https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=2015. With the below code I am able to scrape the table only:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import re
import concurrent.futures
import itertools
from random import randint
from time import sleep

def scraping(year):


    headers =   {
        'accept':'*/*',
        'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36',
        }

    url = f'https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year={year}&sorteer=datekey&page=1'
    #sleep(randint(1,3))
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')

    page_container = soup.find('div',{'class':'pagenumbers'})

    pages = max([int(page['href'].split('=')[-1]) for page in  page_container.find_all('a')])
        

    #info = []
    tl = []
    for page in range(1,pages+1):

        new_url = f'https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year={year}&lang=&page={page}'
        print(new_url)
        
        #sleep(randint(1,3))
        data = requests.get(new_url,headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text,'html.parser')


        table = soup.find('table')
   
    
        for index,row in enumerate(table.find_all('tr')):
            if index == 0:
                continue

            link_ = 'https://aviation-safety.net/'+row.find('a')['href']
            
            #sleep(randint(1,3))
            new_page = requests.get(link_, headers=headers)
            new_soup = BeautifulSoup(new_page.text, 'lxml')
            table1 = new_soup.find('table')
            
           
            for i in table1.find_all('tr'):
                title = i.text
                tl.append(title)
                
                
    df= pd.DataFrame(tl)
    df.columns = ['status'] 
    df.to_csv(f'{year}_aviation-safety_new.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)    
          

if __name__ == "__main__":

    START = 2015
    STOP = 2016

    years = [year for year in range(START,STOP+1)]

    print(f'Scraping {len(years)} years of data')

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=60) as executor:
        final_list = executor.map(scraping,years)
```

**But the data is not organized. The dataframe looks like this:**

[image]

**The outcome should be like this:**

[image]

Comment: It looks you are overwriting `df.columns` with a single item list. What happens if you remove this `df.columns = ['status']`?

Comment: Then instead of status, it would be 0 in the header. That line is just to give the column a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks the values of `tl` are strings, e.g. `'Status:Accident investigation report completed and information captured'`.

Converting the list of strings into a `pd.DataFrame` gets you a single column with all the values in the list.

If you want to use the "name" of the string, e.g. `Status` as a column header, you'll need to separate it from the rest of the text.

```py
# maxsplit of 1 so we don't accidentally split up the values, e.g. time
title, text = title.split(":", maxsplit=1)
```

This looks like

```
('Status', 'Accident investigation report completed and information captured')
```

Now we create a dictionary

```py
row_dict[title] = text
```

Giving us

```
{'Status': 'Accident investigation report completed and information captured'}
```

We will add to this same dictionary in the last loop

```py
# old
for i in table1.find_all('tr'):
    title = i.text
    tl.append(title)
```

```py
# new
row_dict = {}
for i in table1.find_all('tr'):
    title = i.text
    title, text = title.split(":", maxsplit=1)
    row_dict[title] = text
```

After we've gathered all the data from page, i.e. completed the `row_dict` loop, we append to `tl`.

```py
row_dict = {}
for i in table1.find_all('tr'):
    title = i.text
    title, text = title.split(":", maxsplit=1)
    row_dict[title] = text

tl.append(row_dict)
```

All together now

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import re
import concurrent.futures
import itertools
from random import randint
from time import sleep

def scraping(year):


    headers =   {
        'accept':'*/*',
        'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36',
        }

    url = f'https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year={year}&sorteer=datekey&page=1'
    #sleep(randint(1,3))
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')

    page_container = soup.find('div',{'class':'pagenumbers'})

    pages = max([int(page['href'].split('=')[-1]) for page in  page_container.find_all('a')])
        

    #info = []
    tl = []
    for page in range(1,pages+1):

        new_url = f'https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year={year}&lang=&page={page}'
        print(new_url)
        
        #sleep(randint(1,3))
        data = requests.get(new_url,headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text,'html.parser')


        table = soup.find('table')
   
    
        for index,row in enumerate(table.find_all('tr')):
            if index == 0:
                continue

            link_ = 'https://aviation-safety.net/'+row.find('a')['href']
            
            #sleep(randint(1,3))
            new_page = requests.get(link_, headers=headers)
            new_soup = BeautifulSoup(new_page.text, 'lxml')
            table1 = new_soup.find('table')
            
            # make changes here!!!!!!!
            row_dict = {}
            for i in table1.find_all('tr'):
                title = i.text
                title, text = title.split(":", maxsplit=1)
                row_dict[title] = text
            
            tl.append(row_dict)
                
    df= pd.DataFrame(tl)
    df.to_csv(f'{year}_aviation-safety_new.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)    
          

if __name__ == "__main__":

    START = 2015
    STOP = 2016

    years = [year for year in range(START,STOP+1)]

    print(f'Scraping {len(years)} years of data')

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=60) as executor:
        final_list = executor.map(scraping,years)
```

Comment: @ Ian thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I was struggling with this for a while.

Comment: @Kabir -- I enjoyed answering it! You might consider checking out J_H's answer as it may help reduce the number of loops in your function.

Answer (score 1):

The [read_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)
method offers convenient access to such datasets.

```
>>> url = "https://web.archive.org/web/20221027040903/https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=2015"
>>>
>>> dfs = pd.read_html(url)
>>>
>>> df = dfs[1].drop(columns="operator").dropna(axis=1, how="all")
>>> df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.date.str.replace("??-", "01-", regex=False), format="%d-%b-%Y")
>>> df.set_index("date")
                                 type registration  fat.              location cat
date                                                                              
2015-01-02                  Saab 340B       G-LGNL     0       Stornoway Ai...  A1
2015-01-03         Antonov An-26B-100     RA-26082     0       Magadan-Soko...  A1
2015-01-04                  Fokker 50       5Y-SIB     0       Nairobi-Jomo...  A1
2015-01-08  Bombardier Challenger 300       PR-YOU     0       São Paulo-Co...  O1
2015-01-09  Cessna 208B Grand Caravan       8R-GAB     0       Matthews Rid...  A2
...                               ...          ...   ...                   ...  ..
2015-06-11                Eclipse 500       N508JA     0       Sacramento-E...  A2
2015-06-11               Hawker 800XP       N497AG     0       Port Harcour...  A1
2015-06-12             Boeing 737-33A       VH-NLK     0  near Kosrae Airpo...  I2
2015-06-15              Antonov An-2R     RA-84553     0       Tatsinsky di...  A1
2015-06-16        Boeing 737-322 (WL)       LY-FLB     0       Aktau Airpor...  O1

[100 rows x 5 columns]
```

It's hard to control the
[user-agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)
header, so either use a cooperative site,
or do a bit of extra work with requests or curl
to obtain the html text beforehand.